# How to get a string in cookie string using re.search from response headers requests in python

Tags: python, regex

So I want to get the cookie string using the `re` library and `re.search` of a request I made to a website in-order to get the csrf-token thats embedded in the cookie string as such:

```
origin: <website.com>
cookie: id=troti45i2oriwoeit4; csrf-token:eriewotpwep3ou423o4ur9u92342; id2 = wri93ir29ir93i4t9y3i5t4re
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36
```

So I just need the csrf-token that has multiple other stuff I don't really need.

I've tried: `csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]` but it doesn't work

Comment: `csrf-token` is not `csrf_token` and there are no double quotes

Comment: Yea that was just a typo, i fixed it but still error, I'll try the quotes

Comment: If you made the request, why not use the requests library’s facility for retrieving cookies instead of parsing them yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
csrf-token:([^;]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/owor9q/1).

Comment: After many typos I was able to get it working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use regex for this, use the facilities provided by the requests library:

```
response = session.get('http://example.com')
csrf_token = session.cookies['csrf-token']
```

Comment: I decided to use both methods in a `try catch` statement incase the other didn't work. Thanks